# RSpec gives ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, railstutorial.org, mass-assignment

I'm following Railstutorial.org and gets MassAssignment Error when using Rspec.

```
10) User when email format is invalid should be invalid
     Failure/Error: @user = User.new(name:"Example", email:"example@gmail.com",
     ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
       Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation
```

Probably because I try to assign *before* variables in RSpec:

```
  ...
  before do
     @user = User.new(name:"Example", email:"example@gmail.com", 
                                password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar" )
  end

  subject { @user }
  ...
```

Is it possible to disable MassAssignment protection in development or test mode? Or when RSpec is running?
Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: This error will get fixed a bit later in the tutorial when those attributes are marked as ok for mass assignment: "attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation". (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users?version=3.2#sec:has_secure_password)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just avoid the mass assignment:

```
before do
  @user = User.new(name:"Example", email:"example@gmail.com").tap do |u|
    u.password = "foobar"
    u.password_confirmation = "foobar"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked great! Can you tell me what is tap and when or how to use it? or give a link about it? thanks

Comment: `tap` is documented here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap. Note that pre-1.9, `tap` is available as an extension in Rails: http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/Object/tap

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the attributes separately and not use mass assignment.

```
@user = User.new(name:"Example", email:"example@gmail.com")
@user.password = "foobar"
@user.password_confirmation = "foobar"
```

Comment: <DonAdams>missed it by *that* much!</DonAdams>